# Symfony2 constraints entity validation yml

Tags: validation, symfony, entity, type-constraints

I've a many to many relation (user and account). In the user entity, I've private property groups (array collection).

When I try to validate this property (groups) with a simple "NotBlank", it's not work. So I try this below (collection and choice).

I read this http://symfony.com/fr/doc/2.3/reference/constraints/Choice.html
and this http://symfony.com/fr/doc/2.3/reference/constraints/Collection.html but it doesn't work or I don't correctly use them.

Can anybody gives me some help ?

```
/* USER accounts property 

...

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Account", mappedBy="users", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
 */
 private $accounts;

...
```

**Than the userType**

```
...
->add('accounts', 'genemu_jqueryselect2_entity', array(
                    "class"         => "CMiNewsBundle:Account",
                    "property"      => "name",
                    "multiple"      => "true",
                    "query_builder" => function (EntityRepository $er) use ($user)
                    {
                          return $er->createQueryBuilder('acc')
                                    ->join('acc.users','u')
                                    ->where('u.id = :userID')
                                    ->setParameter('userID' , $user);
                    }
                    )
)
...
```

**The validation.yml**

```
CM\Bundle\iNewsBundle\Entity\User:
    properties:

        ...

        accounts:
            - NotBlank: ~

        ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"NotBlank" assert checks if the property === null || property === ''. Since your property is a collection, you probably initialise it as an ArrayCollection in your constructor so it will never be null.

For collections you should use the "Count" assert

http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Count.html

It forces you to set the "maximum" count as well as the minimum so you might want to create your own assert.

Comment: Great, it's work fine ! Thx for your help. Indeed I'll had to create my own assert.

Comment: Hi, in Symfony 3.0, I wasn't forced to set a max value. But to make it work in my form, I had to set the correct validation group to enable the constraint at all. Don't forget this and save big time! ;)